# How to properly use bitwise_and?

Tags: opencv, android, bitwise-and

Hi I'm trying to detect white and yellow lines from road pictures as it's done in this tutorial https://github.com/naokishibuya/car-finding-lane-lines but instead of Python, I'm using Java

```
image = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32S, Scalar.all(0));
white_mask = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32S);
yellow_mask = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32S);
mask = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32S);
masked = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_32S);

// white color mask

lower = new Scalar(200, 200, 200);
upper = new Scalar(255, 255, 255); 
Core.inRange(image, lower, upper, white_mask);
// inRange(Mat src, Scalar lowerb, Scalar upperb, Mat dst)

// yellow color mask

lower = new Scalar(190, 190, 0);
upper = new Scalar(255, 255, 255);
Core.inRange(image, lower, upper, yellow_mask);
// combine the mask
Core.bitwise_or(white_mask, yellow_mask, mask);
//bitwise_or(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dst)
Core.bitwise_and(mask, image, masked);
//bitwise_and(Mat src1, Mat src2, Mat dst)
```

but I'm getting an error during execution time when I use **bitwise_and**

```
 Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:225: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function void cv::binary_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, void (* const*)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, int, int, void*), bool, int)
    ]
        at org.opencv.core.Core.bitwise_and_1(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.core.Core.bitwise_and(Core.java:989)
```

I'm new using OpenCV if you could help me to understand the error and how to solve it I will appreciate it.

Comment: Try debugging the dimensions and type of matrices participating in the `Core.bitwise_and()` function. If any of the metrics has different size of data type then it throws this kind of exception.